# How to make STT vosk from an audio window?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, vosk

I'm using Vosk in Python. How can I get sound from Windows in real-time? I'm looking forward to seeing how it goes around here.

I tried downloading [test_speaker.py](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/python/example/test_speaker.py) example from the `alphacep/vosk-api` repository on GitHub but it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: "doesn't work anymore" does not provide sufficient context. Please include the MCVE and provide error message that you receive (or explain what is wrong with observed behaviour if no error is thrown).

Answer (score 1):

Does the code from this [video](https://youtu.be/XF2WVUVxAGQ?si=CSm_TaiRiBOLIWJg) fit your requirements? The video is in Russian, but I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/VladislavMaksimov/c2b3d054b7128134f2328f3bac92825e) with its code.

You should download one of the language [models](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/models), put it in the same directory with Python's script, and rename the directory containing the model to 'model'. You should also `pip install` two packages: `vosk` and `pyaudio`. Then you can run the script.